# DrawIndexedInstanced() affecting other geometry

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to draw some 2D squares on top of each other.

The first square is 800 x 600 pixels, centered at 0, 0
The second set of squares are each 30 x 30 pixels, moved around on top of the first 2D square

For the first square, I am trying to use simple indexed geometry to render it.

I've tried rendering each individually, and it works. But, when I attempt to render both at the same time, even though I render the first square first, the instancing for the second square seems to interfere by shifting the 800 x 600 square to match the first instance in the instance buffer for the smaller squares, even though I pass new vertex buffers when I switch from the board to each squares. Below is my render code:

```
void Render()
{
    FLOAT color[] = {0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f, 1.0f};

    m_d3dImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_d3dRenderTargetView, color);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_d3dDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(m_d3dInputLayout);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;

    m_d3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_d3dBoardVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_d3dIBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->VSSetShader(m_d3dVShader, NULL, 0);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->PSSetShader(m_d3dPShader, NULL, 0);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &m_d3dCBPerObject);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_samLinear);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_d3dBoardSRV);

    XMMATRIX worldViewProj = m_world * m_view * m_proj;
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_cbPerObject.WorldViewProj, worldViewProj);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    m_d3dImmediateContext->Map(m_d3dCBPerObject, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    CopyMemory(mappedResource.pData, &m_cbPerObject, sizeof(struct CBPerObject));
    m_d3dImmediateContext->Unmap(m_d3dCBPerObject, 0);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(m_indexCount, 0, 0);

    UINT blockStride[2] = {sizeof(Vertex), sizeof(Instance)};
    UINT blockOffset[2] = {0, 0};

    ID3D11Buffer *vBuffers[2] = {m_d3dBlockVBuffer, m_d3dBlockInstVBuffer};

    m_d3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 2, vBuffers, blockStride, blockOffset);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_d3dIBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->VSSetShader(m_d3dVShader, NULL, 0);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->PSSetShader(m_d3dPShader, NULL, 0);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &m_d3dCBPerObject);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_samLinear);
    m_d3dImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_d3dBlockSRV);

    worldViewProj = m_world * m_view * m_proj;
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_cbPerObject.WorldViewProj, worldViewProj);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource2;
    m_d3dImmediateContext->Map(m_d3dCBPerObject, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource2);
    CopyMemory(mappedResource2.pData, &m_cbPerObject, sizeof(struct CBPerObject));
    m_d3dImmediateContext->Unmap(m_d3dCBPerObject, 0);

    m_d3dImmediateContext->DrawIndexedInstanced(m_indexCount, 4, 0, 0, 0);

    m_d3dSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Am I doing something fundamentally incorrect? The board is the 800 x 600 square, and the block is the 30 x 30 square. On top of the board, I want to render multiple squares basically.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting an input layout for the second vertex buffer. You set it before rendering m_d3dBoardVBuffer, but you dont set a unique one before rendering vBuffers.